# quiero producir este efecto de encimado de input con icono que esta en la imagen

Tags: css, html5, css3

Este efecto de la carita feliz dentro del input como pueden ver, ya que los inputs se alargan al darles click, por alguna razón este efecto si lo logro en full-screen pero NO en los media queries, a que se debe esto? los iconos están con posición absoluta y los inputs en posicion relativa por lo que deberia de funcionar pero no pasa, lo que si pasa es que los iconos son expulsados arriba del input quedando desalineados, esto solo pasa en tamaños para mobiles.
lo raro es que aca en este link https://codepen.io/CeciPeque/full/axYRLr no funciona pero aqui en este otro si https://codepen.io/CeciPeque/pen/axYRLr a que se debe esto? por cierto tengo 5 errores en el editor de codepen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No veo el error del que hablas, funciona bien en ambos enlaces

Comment: Si ya esta correcto, lo siento.